# How do I show all ipv4 and ipv6 addresses by using grep

Tags: grep, ipv6, ip-address, ipv4

I'm trying to grep `inet addr` and `inet 6 addr` from `ifconfig`. I can grep `inet addr` or `inet6 addr` alone only.

How can I show both IPV4 and IPV6 addresses in one command?

Comment: `ifconfig | grep inet*` should be able to do it.

Comment: Whew thank you so much. you saved me

Comment: ... you can always use `grep -e PAT1 -e PAT2 ...` to match multiple alternate patterns

Comment: @Terrance The pattern should be enclosed in quotes: `grep 'inet*'` - to avoid surprises in case the current directory contains a file with a name starting with `inet`.

Comment: @Tilman It was only a 30 second comment.  You can feel free to write an answer if you want.  :)

Comment: @Terrance I didn't mean to rebuke you, just to remove a possible source of perplexity for unsuspecting readers.

Comment: @DOS You should [edit] your question and show the code you are trying, the input you use, the actual output you get and the desired output.